# Determine the largest real number in [0,2] $\beta$ a double series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I wish to determine the largest real number $\beta \in [0,2]$ for which the following converges:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(i^2+j^2)^{\beta-1}}{(ij)^3}
\end{align}
now, my first attempt is either to try to say, ok, $\beta=2$ and then see that $\beta$ is to large... but I need to either show that it really is $\beta-\epsilon$ for where $\epsilon$ is arbitrarly small or determine the exact value. So, my second attempt is to use bionomial expansions, where $()_k$ is the falling factorial:

\begin{align}
 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^3j^3} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\beta-1)_k}{k!}(i^2)^{\beta-1-k}(j^2)^k
\end{align}
and then try to move stuff in...but there i get stuck. The third attempt is to see use Cauchy's condensation criterion, but no dice. any suggestions?

Comment: To assure the sum is finite, we need to know that we sum finite numbers. And this can be only when $\beta<2$.

Comment: @Jakobian:  No, when $\beta=1$ the exponent in the numerator is $0$, so the numerator is $1$ and we get a finite sum.  I missed the $-1$ initially, too.

Comment: @RossMillikan I meant $\beta = 2$, not $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Use $$(i^2+j^2)^{\beta-1} \geq i^{2(\beta-1)}$$ to show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(i^2+j^2)^{\beta-1}}{(ij)^3} = \infty \quad \text{for $\beta=2$}.$$ Hence, $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(i^2+j^2)^{\beta-1}}{(ij)^3} = \infty \quad \text{for $\beta=2$}.$$
2. Prove (or recall) that $(x+y)^p \leq x^p + y^p$ for any $x,y>0$ and $p \in (0,1)$.
3. Show that $$(i^2+j^2)^{\beta-1} \leq \begin{cases} i^{2(\beta-1)} + j^{2(\beta-1)}, & \beta \in (1,2) \\ 1, & \beta \in [0,1] \end{cases}$$ for any $i,j \geq 1$.
4. Use Step 3 to prove that $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(i^2+j^2)^{\beta-1}}{(ij)^3} < \infty \quad \text{for $\beta \in (0,2)$}.$$

Comment: @edo Well, you didn't mention that you already know all of that. It's hard to say what your advisor wants to hear from you; certainly $$\sup\{\beta; \text{the series converges for $\beta$\}}=2$$ but the series fails to converge for $\beta=2$. There is really not more to say about this.